# Make Ubuntu resume to previous session after forced shutdown

Tags: login, session

Sometimes Ubuntu 16 freezes randomly and the option i am left to do is do a forced shutdown.

Windows can be configured easily to resume previous 'session' after an unexpected shutdown. Can the same be done in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible:  https://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: @Terrance that method is for everytime when we want to restore previous session. im saying that when an accident shutdown happens so in that case  my session should restore and not when i manually shutdown. but still helpful though